# Any or A/An in negative sentences?

Tags: articles, determiners

1. I don't have any children.
2. I don't have a child.

What are the differences between them?

Are there any circumstances that make them noninterchangeable??

Comment: Note that [*child*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/child) has multiple senses. In different contexts, *any children* could mean *any sons or daughters* and *a child* could mean *a son or daughter less than eighteen years old*.

Comment: Also, in a certain semantic context (say you are entering a place where only *one* child is allowed to accompany an adult), one or the other might be a more appropriate expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in meaning here. "Any children" means "one or more children", whereas "a child" means "one child".

[Any](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/any)

Comment: Are they interchangeable in any of circumstances?

Comment: If either a definite singular or plural sense is required, you could use 'a' for the singular and 'any' for the plural, so you might use "I don't have a child" to correct someone who says e.g. "This gift is for your child", and "I don't have any children" to reply to "These gifts are for your children".